# Can't install package

Tags: android, libraries

Trying to setup environment for android ROM development, but the `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386` package is not installing. Getting error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libcheese-gtk23 : Depends: libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 (>= 0.91.8) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
libcheese7 : Depends: libclutter-gst-2.0-0 (>= 0.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: gstreamer1.0-clutter but it is not going to be installed
libclutter-1.0-0 : Depends: libcogl-pango15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4)
                    Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 7.2)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.2. Need help...

Update: Meanwhile I installed libglapi-mesa-lts-saucy:i386    Is it fine now?

Answer (score 0):

verify your architecture if it's 64 bits, you don't install all dependence.

and too verify PPAs install on your Ubuntu.

How to do OK:

> sudo aptitude install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386

Comment: There is no aptitude in Ubuntu installations.

Comment: Meanwhile, I installed libglapi-mesa-lts-saucy:i386